# Always map null object to null

Tags: dozer

I'm looking for a way to map every object that is null to null instead of `"org.dozer.MappingException: Source object must not be null"` error. 
I don't want to enumerate every class and say that null maps to null, I want to specify this as a general rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one is a generic exception saying that you should not pass *null* object as a top level bean to *mapper.map(src, dest)* method. So putting guard check before invoking Dozer should help.

```
if (src == null) return null;
return dozer.map(src, dest);
```

In addition, *'map-null'* policy is enabled by default, but it applies only to elements inside the bean you want to map (not top-level). So Dozer will properly map `'user.id'` if it is null value. In the next version there will be a possibility to apply *'map-null'* on global level as well without specifying each class. However this would only help to disable null mapping, since it is enabled by default.

Comment: How to change map null policy? I don't want to map if fields inside the beans are null